# Why is this api call returning four numbers with a length of 8?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying this new API that returns numbers. There are four returned. When the function below is called, you'll see four numbers in the terminal but the length of the string is 8. I do not know why. I am trying to manipulate the data to return a horizontal string of four numbers.

```
import requests

def randomApi():
    r = requests.get('https://www.random.org/integers/?num=4&min=0&max=7&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new')
    return ''.join(r.text)

print(randomApi())
print(len(randomApi()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API returns a string like `'5\n2\n5\n7\n'` where the numbers are separated by newlines (represented here by the escape sequence `\n`). The newline characters contribute to the length of the string, so this string has a length of 8 - four digits plus four newline characters.

To convert them to a "horizontal" string, you can use `.replace` to convert the newlines to spaces. I suggest using `.strip()` first to remove the newline at the end of the string, since you probably don't want an extra space at the end of your result.

```py
>>> s = randomApi()
>>> s.strip().replace('\n', ' ')
'3 7 4 7'
```

Comment: Much appreciated. Thank you.